# Permutations with Restrictions

Tags: java, permutation

In java, I'm trying to find a way to generate permutations based on restrictions. How can I generate the number of permutations (with the restrictions in mind), or at least know how many?

**Edit: Simple Restriction Definition:**

Possible values: `A, B, C`

Restrictions: `a[0] == a[1]` and `a[0] != [2]`

Example dataset:

```
AABA
AABB
AABC
AACA
AACB
AACC
BBAA
BBAB
BBAC
BBCA
BBCB
BBCC
CCAA
CCAB
CCAC
CCBA
CCBB
CCBC
```

I've tried generating all permutations and then subtracting the incompatible ones, this seems terribly inefficient. How can I do this efficiently? **I only need to count the permutations, however it would be good to generate them all.**

Comment: Do you want to generate the permutations or just count them? Do you know how to do either of these by hand? Use your example as a starting point to figure out how to do this with a piece of paper and a pencil.

Comment: I need to just count them. If possible, it would be good to return them all, and I did do it by hand by doing the example above.

Comment: An idea I had was to increment the ones that are supposed to be the same, then skip the values that are not valid

Comment: As a more complex example, how many 4-digit numbers are there with the first two digits the same and the third digit different than the first two? This is harder to list, but you should be able to count them fairly quickly.

Comment: How about this @Code-Guru - normally the number of permutations for this is 4^3, if you are binding the first two together though, this will instead be 3^3. Okay, this is fine, however I need the `!=` exceptions. How do I calculate these?

Comment: How did you get `4^3`?

Comment: It is 3^4, my mistake, was typing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25988/discussion-between-code-guru-and-christian-stewart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to count the sequences rather than generate them, then you can borrow some ideas from combinatorics. First note that without restrictions there are `3*3*3*3` 4-character strings from the "alphabet" {A, B, C}. If we add the restriction that the first and second character must be the same, then there are `3*1*3*3` possible strings. If, on the other hand, we add the restriction that the first and third character *cannot* be the same, then there are `3*3*2*3` possibilities.

If the restrictions are part of the input to your program, then you can use these two examples to create a general solution by assigning the number of choices to each character in the string.

Comment: Please see comment thread for chain of reasoning: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25988/discussion-between-code-guru-and-christian-stewart

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, those are not [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation), but rather sequences over a finite domain.

A trivial algorithm is to generate all sequences, and only output those sequences that satisfy the restrictions. Generating all sequences of length n over a domain A is quite easy with recursion:

```
class SequenceGenerator {
    char[] domain;
    char[] sequence;
    int n;

    void generate(int i) {
        if (i == n) {
            System.out.println(new String(sequence));
        } else {
            for (char c : domain) {
                sequence[i] = c;
                generate(i + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A more refined algorithm would check partially formed sequences. For instance, if you know your sequence starts with AB, you already know it will not satisfy the restriction sequence[0] == sequence[1], so there is no point in filling in the remaining elements:

```
abstract class PickySequenceGenerator extends SequenceGenerator {

    @Override
    void generate(int i) {
        if (possible(i)) {
            super.generate(i);
        }
    }

    /** @return whether a sequence starting with the first i elements of {@link #sequence} can still satisfy all constraints */
    abstract boolean possible(int i);
}
```

For extra efficiency, you can assign values to the most constrained sequence elements first.

Comment: You're right, these are more combinations and definitely not permutations

Comment: Not quite, because in a combination order would not matter, while here, restrictions are sensitive to element indices.

Comment: Upvote for your work, sir, but I have to give this one to Code-Guru because of his great work explaining it to me step by step over some time.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (char a0='A'; a0<='C'; a0++) {
  char a1=a0;
  for (char a2='A'; a2<='C'; a2++) {
    if (a0 != a2) {
      for (char a3='A'; a3<='C'; a3++) {
         a.append(a0 + a1 + a2 + a3);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(pseudocode, but I think you get the picture)

Comment: Yes, yes, but the thing is **these restrictions change** therefore hardcoding like this won't work